# How to get bone transformation matrix from head tail and roll

Tags: c++, animation, math

In blender each bone has head tail and roll.
I need to get one transformation matrix from that bone presentation.
I've found reverse operation, if we have matrix T then:
head = T * (0,0,0)
tail = T * (0,1,0)

How to build this matrix?

Comment: This might belong more to gamedev.SE.

Comment: Do you think that animation is only gamedev? I don't create games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for a 4x4 matrix that does not contain perspective transforms. So the last row is `(0, 0, 0, 1)`. The mappings of two principal vectors are given, yielding this partial matrix:

```
/      tail.x         head.x \
|      tail.y         head.y |
|      tail.z         head.z |
\ 0    0         0    1      /
```

There are still two vectors left. That's where the roll comes into play. Both vectors should be perpendicular to `tail` and to each other. In order to solve this, we need a reference direction (that basically states where one of the vectors - in this case the x-vector- is directed at the 0 angle). Then we can do:

```
r = rotate reference about tail by roll
z = cross(r, tail)
x = cross(tail, z)
```

Yielding this complete matrix:

```
/ x.x  tail.x   z.x  head.x \
| x.y  tail.y   z.y  head.y |
| x.z  tail.z   z.z  head.z |
\ 0    0        0    1      /
```

The one thing you need to find out is the reference vector. There should be even two of them (in case `tail` is parallel to the first one). Or if you can find any reference on the meaning of `roll`, you should adapt the calculations accordingly.

Comment: What did you mean about, r = rotate reference about tail by roll, can you exlain? Thanks

Comment: That means to rotate the vector `reference` using the axis `tail` and angle `roll`.